# After upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11 receiving a loader constraint violation

Tags: java, maven, classloader, java-11

I am upgrading a behemoth application from **Java 8** to **Java 11**.  We are still building with **Java 8** but running with **Java 11**.

I am seeing a class not properly loading because of a loader constraint violation. The code base imports this class via a jar file in a maven dependency.  If we remove the jar file before starting the application the issue goes away.

The error is below:

> loader constraint violation: loader 'bootstrap' wants to load
>   interface org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator. A different interface
>   with the same name was previously loaded by com.app.CustomClassLoader
>   @9626f9, parent loader java.net.URLClassLoader @13afaa3)

I found that previously this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader first.  Now it's loaded by the custom application loader first.  The order difference is below:

**Java 8:**

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/01/08 11:34:30.626 | [Loaded
>   org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator from
>   /java-1.8.0_221.i586/jre/lib/rt.jar] INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/01/08
>   11:34:34.184 | [Loaded org.dom4j.NodeIterator from
>   file:/webapps/lib/dom4j-x.x.x.jar]

In **Java 11**

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/01/07 17:45:49.426 | [3.787s][info
>   ][class,load] org.dom4j.NodeIterator source:
>   file:/webapps/lib/dom4j-x.x.x.jar INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/01/07
>   17:46:15.772 | [30.210s][info   ][class,load  ]
>   org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator source:
>   file:/webapps/lib/xml-x.x.x.jar INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/01/07
>   17:46:15.772 | [30.210s][info   ][class,load  ]
>   org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator source: jrt:/java.xml

Manually removing `xml-x.x.x.jar` before startup prevents this from happening.  I am trying to resolve this without removing that jar or the dependency.  Is there a way to force the bootstrap class loader into loading the `xml-x.x.x.jar` file first?  I tried adding the jar file in the bootclasspath but it did not resolve it.

Comment: I should add that we load the xml-x.x.x.jar dependency via maven in multiple places.    Removing it from the maven dependency pom files is very difficult due to heavy reliance on it during build.

Comment: any updates on this issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this artifact only during build, you can change its scope to provided
 `<scope>provided</scope>`, this way maven won't load this dependency for runtime

Comment: This works however if you want to also run on Java 8 as well as Java 11 you may run into issues if the removed dependency has classes that Java 8 does not.