# java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, classcastexception

I'm trying to write a Java unit test for the below code

public class PrintnetRequestTranslator extends RequestTranslator<MutationOverviewDocRequest, RequestContent> {

```
public PrintnetRequestTranslator(final MutationOverviewDocRequest mutationOverviewDocRequest) {
    super(mutationOverviewDocRequest);
}

private static final JAXBContext JAXB_CONTEXT;

static {
    try {
        JAXB_CONTEXT =
                JAXBContext.newInstance("printnet.generated");
    } catch (final JAXBException ex) {
        throw new CardLimitsServiceException(ex);
    }
}



private static final String KOP_FALSE = "false";

@Override
public RequestContent translateRequest() {

    final RequestContent requestContent = new RequestContent();
    requestContent.setOutputFormat(GjOutputFormatType.PDF);

    final Delivery delivery = new Delivery();

    requestContent.setDelivery(delivery);

    delivery.setCreationDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
    final Delivery.Document document = new Delivery.Document();
    document.setName("Mutatieoverzicht");
    document.setNumberOfCopies(1);
    final Delivery.Document.GenericData genericData = new Delivery.Document.GenericData();
    final Delivery.Document.GenericData.Bank bank = new Delivery.Document.GenericData.Bank();
    bank.setBankCode(String.valueOf(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getLocalBank().getBankCode()));
    final Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients clients = new Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients();
    final Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients.Client client = new Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients.Client();

    client.setId(getRequest().getCustomerRelationId());
    client.setInitials(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getNaturalPersonDetails().getNameInitial());
    client.setSurname(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getNaturalPersonDetails().getSurname());
    client.setDateOfBirth((getRequest().getRelationDetails().getBirthDate()).toString());
    client.setGender((getRequest().getRelationDetails().getGenderCode()));

    final Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients.Client.Address address =
            new Delivery.Document.GenericData.Clients.Client.Address();
    address.setStreet(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getAddress().getStreetName());
    address.setCity(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getAddress().getCityName());
    address.setPostCode(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getAddress().getPostalCode());
    address.setCountry(getRequest().getRelationDetails().getAddress().getCountryCode());

    client.setAddress(address);
    clients.withClients(client);
    genericData.setBank(bank);
    genericData.withClients(clients);
    document.setGenericData(genericData);

    final Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht mutatieOverzicht = new Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht();
    mutatieOverzicht
        .setTitle(ACCOUNT_TYPE_MAP.getOrDefault(getRequest().getPackageProductTypeCode(), "Rabo Rekening"));
    mutatieOverzicht.setOndertekenblokIndicator(KOP_FALSE);
    mutatieOverzicht.setVerkoopOnderVoorbehoudIndicator(KOP_FALSE);
    final Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht.Product product = new Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht.Product();

    product.getDetailRegels()
        .add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_NAME_MAP.getOrDefault(getRequest().getCardProductTypeCode(), "Rabopas"),
            JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER, DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_NEW_VALUE, "true"));
    product.getDetailRegels()
        .add(getDetails(
            new StringJoiner(JOINER_DELIMITER).add(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_IBAN).add(getRequest().getIban()).toString(),
            JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER, JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER, KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels().add(
        getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_PASSNUMBER, getRequest().getCardNumber(), JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER, KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels()
        .add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_GIVENNAME, JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER,
            getProductGivenName(getRequest().getRelationDetails(), getRequest().getRetrieveDebitCardToken()),
            KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels()
        .add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_GEALIMIT,
            new StringJoiner(JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER).add(getFormattedAmount(getRequest().getOldAtmLimit()))
                .add(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_EURO).toString(),
            new StringJoiner(JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER).add(getFormattedAmount(getRequest().getNewAtmLimit()))
                .add(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_EURO).toString(),
            KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels().add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_PERIOD, getRequest().getAtmLimitPeriod(),
        getRequest().getAtmLimitPeriod(), KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels()
        .add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_BEALIMIT,
            new StringJoiner(JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER).add(getFormattedAmount(getRequest().getOldPosLimit()))
                .add(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_EURO).toString(),
            new StringJoiner(JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER).add(getFormattedAmount(getRequest().getNewPosLimit()))
                .add(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_EURO).toString(),
            KOP_FALSE));
    product.getDetailRegels().add(getDetails(DOCUMENT_PRODUCT_PERIOD, getRequest().getPosLimitPeriod(),
        getRequest().getPosLimitPeriod(), KOP_FALSE));
    mutatieOverzicht.setProduct(product);
    document.setMutatieOverzicht(mutatieOverzicht);
    delivery.withDocuments(document);
    requestContent.setDelivery(getDocument(delivery));
    return requestContent;

}



@Override
public ServiceInfo getServiceInfo() {
    return ServiceInfo.PRINTNET_GENERATE_DOCUMENT;
}

private Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht.Product.DetailRegel getDetails(final String productName,
                                                                          final String oldValue,
                                                                          final String newValue, final String kop)
{
    final Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht.Product.DetailRegel detailRegel =
            new Delivery.Document.MutatieOverzicht.Product.DetailRegel();

    detailRegel.setOmschrijving(productName);
    detailRegel.setOudeWaarde(oldValue);
    detailRegel.setNieuweWaarde(newValue);
    detailRegel.setKop(kop);
    return detailRegel;

}

private String getProductGivenName(final RelationResponse relationDetails,
                                   final RetrieveDebitCardToken retrieveDebitCardToken)
{
    final StringJoiner productGivenName = new StringJoiner(JOINER_SPACE_DELIMITER);
    if (relationDetails.getOrganisationLegalName() == null) {
        addIfNotEmpty(productGivenName, relationDetails.getNaturalPersonDetails().getNameInitial());
        addIfNotEmpty(productGivenName, relationDetails.getNaturalPersonDetails().getSurnamePrefix());
        addIfNotEmpty(productGivenName, relationDetails.getNaturalPersonDetails().getSurname());
    } else {
        addIfNotEmpty(productGivenName, retrieveDebitCardToken.getTokenText1());
    }
    return productGivenName.toString();
}

private void addIfNotEmpty(final StringJoiner stringJoiner, final String join) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(join)) {
        stringJoiner.add(join);
    }
}

private Element getDocument(final Object any) {
    try {
        final DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        df.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        df.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
        final DocumentBuilder db = df.newDocumentBuilder();

        final org.w3c.dom.Document document = db.newDocument();
        final Marshaller marshaller = JAXB_CONTEXT.createMarshaller();

        marshaller.marshal(any, document);
        return document.getDocumentElement();
    } catch (final ParserConfigurationException | JAXBException ex) {
        throw new CardLimitsServiceException(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the RequestContent Class

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "outputFormat",
    "delivery"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "RequestContent")
public class RequestContent {

    @XmlElement(name = "OutputFormat", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected GjOutputFormatType outputFormat;
    @XmlElement(name = "Delivery", required = true)
    protected Object delivery;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the outputFormat property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link GjOutputFormatType }
     *     
     */
    public GjOutputFormatType getOutputFormat() {
        return outputFormat;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the outputFormat property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link GjOutputFormatType }
     *     
     */
    public void setOutputFormat(GjOutputFormatType value) {
        this.outputFormat = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the delivery property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public Object getDelivery() {
        return delivery;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the delivery property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setDelivery(Object value) {
        this.delivery = value;
    }

    public RequestContent withOutputFormat(GjOutputFormatType value) {
        setOutputFormat(value);
        return this;
    }

    public RequestContent withDelivery(Object value) {
        setDelivery(value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Here is my unit test code

class PrintnetRequestTranslatorTest {

```
private PrintnetRequestTranslator classUnderTest;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    classUnderTest = new PrintnetRequestTranslator(TestData.mockMutationDocumentRequest());
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Printnet Translator Success Scenario")
void testPrintnetRequestSuccess() {
    final var result = classUnderTest.translateRequest();
    final Delivery delivery = (Delivery) result.getDelivery();
    assertAll("Printnet Request Translator Test : ",
        () -> assertEquals(TestUtils.PRINTNET_OUTPUT_FORMAT, result.getOutputFormat().toString()));

}
```

}

I'm getting the below error when I' trying to cast Delivery class. `java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class printnet.generated.Delivery (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap'; ......printnet.generated.Delivery is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

How can I solve this error/write a unit test for the above class?

Comment: You need to show the RequestContent class

Comment: You see a clash in the class name ElementNSImpl: from different packages. Look at the imports, one must be for a wrong XML package. This does not need to be ElementNSImpl, but could be near. But a ElementNSImpl object must exist, look for the interface Element(NS).

Comment: @tgdavies Have added the RequestContent class

Comment: "is in module java.xml of .." sounds very like a "java 11 update issue"... https://stackoverflow.com/q/59817466/592355 e.a. (ide, build-tool related)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception, and noticed, that my unmarshaller left the ElementNSImpl instead of my own class in the list.

The second answer in this post
[Intermittent ClassCastException from ElementNSImpl to own type during unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377865/intermittent-classcastexception-from-elementnsimpl-to-own-type-during-unmarshall)
solved it for me.